# Interpreting ARIMA for Interrupted Time Series Analysis

Tags: r, time-series, intervention-analysis

I want to test for efficacy of an intervention. I have pre- and post-intervention data and I used `auto.arima` to find the best fit for the two data sets.

I'm stuck in the actual use of these models now. What do I do with the `auto.arima` fit? Can I graph it and test for statistically significant differences in the coefficients? If so, how do I graph it?

This is what I have right now ( specified from `auto.arima`)

`myPreFit<-arima(myPre,order=c(0,1,0))`

`myPostFit<-arima(myPost,order=c(1,0,1))`

Comment: Do you believe that your series is well-modeled by an ARIMA process, but that the entire ARIMA structure may have changed due to the intervention? Does the fact that, say, the series is now better described by including an MA term mean something to you, scientifically? If you expect something simpler like "the mean/drift may have changed due to the intervention", you should include an intervention dummy as an exogenous regressor, use `forecast::auto.arima` on *that* model, and then test the dummy coefficient.

Comment: With an MA term, there is a definite conclusion I am drawing, scientifically.

I don't see how using `forecast()` will help determine the difference between the models.

Comment: Chris Haug is not suggesting to use the function `forecast` but the package `forecast` because `forecast::auto.arima` is used to refer to function `auto.arima` from package `forecast`.

Answer (score 0):

Time series intervention analysis is not like this. First, you have to model regular ARIMA model for preintervention period and find the order of appropriate ARIMA model. Then you have to use the order in ARIMAX model (taking whole period, pre+post intervention), including a dummy variable.

```
model1 = forecast::auto.arima(ts_model1, trace = TRUE, seasonal = TRUE, 
                              stationary = FALSE, ic = c("aicc", "aic", "bic"),
                              stepwise = TRUE, allowmean = TRUE, allowdrift = TRUE)

# ts_model1 is only for preintervention period
# Best model: ARIMA(1,1,1)(1,0,0)[12]

model2 = TSA::arimax(ts_model2, order = c(1, 1, 1),
                     seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 0), period = 12),
                     xreg = ts_model4, 
                     method = c("CSS-ML", "ML", "CSS"),
                     kappa = 1e+06, xtransf = dummy, transfer = list(c(1,0)))
```

I hope you understand.

Comment: This is completely unreadable I  am afraid. https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting may help you here to edit it so e can read it.